# Questions regarding the pygame.mask function

Tags: python, function, pygame, mask

So I read the documentation of pygame but I could not understand it clearly. I recently asked a question about bitmap fonts and I got some code as my answer; here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
i = 0
text = "hello how are you?"
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    letter = text[i]
    text_1 = font.render(letter, True, (255, 255, 255))

    bw, bh = font.size(letter)
    glyph_rect = pygame.mask.from_surface(text_1).get_bounding_rects()
    # print(glyph_rect)
    if glyph_rect:
        gh = glyph_rect[0].height
        print(f'letter {letter}  bitmap height: {bh}  glyph height: {gh}')

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(text_1, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

    i += 1
    run = i < len(text)

pygame.quit()
```

So, my questions are on the line `glyph_rect = pygame.mask.from_surface(text_1).get_bounding_rects()`.

1. What does the `pygame.mask.from_surface()` function do?
2. What does the line `glyph_rect = pygame.mask.from_surface(text_1).get_bounding_rects()` do?
3. What arguments does the variable `glyph_rect` return, and what is the meaning of those arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.mask.from_surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) creates a [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) object form a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).
A *Surface* is bitmap. A *Mask* is an 2 dimensional array with [Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) values. The *Mask* created is the size of the _Surface. A field is `True` if the corresponding pixel in the surface is not transparent, and `False` if it is transparent.

[`pygame.mask.Mask.get_bounding_rects`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.get_bounding_rects) creates a list of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects. Each rectangle describes a bounding area of connected pixles.
If the *Surface* contains exactly 1 connected image, you will get exactly 1 rectangle surrounding the image.

---

See the example. The black rectangle is the *Surface* rectangle and the red rectangle is the bound rectangle of the connected component:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/ImageHitbox](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ImageHitbox#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

def getMaskRect(surf, top = 0, left = 0):
    surf_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(surf)
    rect_list = surf_mask.get_bounding_rects()
    surf_mask_rect = rect_list[0].unionall(rect_list)
    surf_mask_rect.move_ip(top, left)
    return surf_mask_rect

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

try:
    my_image = pygame.image.load('Bomb-256.png')
except:
    my_image = pygame.Surface((200, 200), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.circle(my_image, (0, 128, 0), (60, 60), 40)
    pygame.draw.circle(my_image, (0, 0, 128), (100, 150), 40)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pos = window.get_rect().center
    my_image_rect = my_image.get_rect(center = pos)
    my_image_mask_rect = getMaskRect(my_image, *my_image_rect.topleft)

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(my_image, my_image_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), my_image_rect, 3)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), my_image_mask_rect, 3)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```