# How do i fix the hitbox for my pygame sprite barring resizing every image?

Tags: python, pygame, sdl, game-physics, game-development

```
class Entity():
    def __init__(self, char_type, x, y, scale):
        self.char_type = char_type
        self.flip = False
        self.direction = 1
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jump = False
        self.attacking = False
        self.animation_list = []
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.action = 0
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        #load all images 
        animation_types = ['idle', 'run', 'jump', 'attack', 'death', 'hit']
        for animation in animation_types:
            #reset temporary list of images
            temp_list = []
            #count number of files in the folder
            num_of_frames = len(os.listdir(f"img/{self.char_type}/{animation}"))
            for i in range(num_of_frames-2):
                img = pygame.image.load(f"img/{self.char_type}/{animation}/{i}.png")
                img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (img.get_width()*scale,img.get_height()*3))
                temp_list.append(img)
            self.animation_list.append(temp_list)

        self.image = self.animation_list[self.action][self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
```

This is my first time attempting a pygame project and i'm having issues. Basically the frames are really big so the rectangle I made with `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` to create the hitbox for my playable character is massive. [what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzCr5.png) I tried solving this by using `self.rect = self.image.get_bounding_rect()`This did solve the issue with having a massive rectangle however it made the image which I drew using the following method

```
def draw(self, surface):
 img = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, self.flip, False)
 pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0 , 0), self.rect)
 surface.blit(img, self.rect)
```

to not be centered over the rectangle which should be its hitbox. That ended up looking like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mS2R.png) I think that the issue is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to get the correct dimensions for a pygame rectangle created from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523501/questions-regarding-the-pygame-mask-function/67523631#67523631) and [How can I crop an image with Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239769/how-can-i-crop-an-image-with-pygame/65627793#65627793):

Use [`pygame.Surface.get_bounding_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_bounding_rect) and [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) to get  a cropped region from your image.

e.g.:

```py
original_image = pygame.image.load(f"img/{self.char_type}/{animation}/{i}.png")
crop_rect = original_image.get_bounding_rect()
cropped_image = original_image.subsurface(crop_rect).copy()

img = pygame.transform.scale(cropped_image,
    (cropped_image.get_width()*scale, cropped_image.get_height()*3))
```